# Database Not Updatable (Form issue)

Tags: ms-access

Using Access to aggregate multiple linked tables together via the code below using a form. The module works correctly by selecting it independently via a macro, but when the macro is activated via a button in a form it is not activating correctly and stops at Do.CmdOpenQuery ("XYZ Step 2") Would anyone have an idea what is causing the error in the form instance?

CODE:
`Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

```
Public Function RunQueries()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.OpenQuery ("XYZ (Step 1)")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("XYZ (Step 2)")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("XYZ (Step 3)")
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "XYZ (Step 3)", acFormatXLSX, , True

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox "If you are seeing this, Congrats."

End Function`
```

Checked the Settings of the button, Modified code to ignore screens.

Comment: What do these queries do? Not sure what you mean by "aggregate multiple linked tables together". What do you mean by "ignore screens"?

Comment: Apologies, not the most tech savvy here. I have about ~10 different linked tables(excel) that command 1 Unions, with command 2 creating a table in access and overwriting the old table as the macro is ran. by ignore screens, it is a function of the setwarnings - it automatically goes through the warnings without user input.

Comment: There is no need to "Open" a UNION query. The second command to create and overwrite table fails? No idea why macro would work and VBA not. However, if table structure remains same, alternative is to just DELETE records then INSERT new.

Comment: Interesting - would there be a better alternative than the "OpenQuery" in this case for the first command? It's only function is to UNION ALL all existing spreadsheets. And yes, the second command is where this unravels and becomes not updateable and exactly as you said it. I'll give the DELETE records and INSERT a go and see if that fixes things!

Comment: My point is, nothing is required. You have a query object with UNION syntax. It just has to be there, like a table.